# facing issue with image url in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, asset-pipeline, development-environment, production-environment

i have this type of code

```
module PhotosHelper 
  def photo_default_image_url(photo)
    if photo.image_url == "/assets/image.jpg"
        URI.join(root_url, "/assets/image.jpg")
    else
        photo.image_url(:thumb)
    end
  end
end

and image code is 

 <img src="<%= photo_default_image_url(@photo) %>">
```

its working fine for development mood.

i got url like this for image

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/image.jpg
```

but its not working in production mood

i got url like this for image

```
/image.jpg
```

please help me to solve this.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Did you precomple your assets**.As in `production`,the rails looks for `assets` in `public` folder and **not** in `assets` folder.i might be wrong but it can be because of asset pipeline.You can resolve this by manually adding the image in `public` folder and then running `rake assets:precompile` so that it is available in `public` folder.
*Morever,for the same stuff to handle default picture,you can use my code as well.*

```
###in picture.rb
## belongs_to :user
MISSING_PICTURE_URL = '/assets/picture_missing.png'

##in user.rb
##has_many :pictures
def get_picture_url
  self.pictures.exists? ? self.pictures.sample.picture.expiring_url(:medium) : Picture::MISSING_PICTURE_URL

end
```

so i can easily use `@user.get_picture_url` and it works **great**.
**Also one more thing to note here,i am using use exists? and not present?**